# How can i Plot arrows in a existing mplsoccer pitch?

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to do the tutorial of McKay Johns on YT (reference to the Jupyter Notebook to see the data (https://github.com/mckayjohns/passmap/blob/main/Pass%20map%20tutorial.ipynb).

I understood everything but I wanted to do a little change. I wanted to change plt.plot(...) with:

plt.arrow(df['x'][x],df['y'][x], df['endX'][x] - df['x'][x], df['endY'][x]-df['y'][x],
shape='full', color='green')

But the problem is, I still can't see the arrows. I tried multiple changes but I've failed. So I'd like to ask you in the group.

Below you can see the code.

```
## Read in the data
df = pd.read_csv('...\Codes\Plotting_Passes\messibetis.csv')

#convert the data to match the mplsoccer statsbomb pitch
#to see how to create the pitch, watch the video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55k1mCRyd2k
df['x'] = df['x']*1.2
df['y'] = df['y']*.8
df['endX'] = df['endX']*1.2
df['endY'] = df['endY']*.8

# Set Base
fig ,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13.5,8))
# Change background color of base
fig.set_facecolor('#22312b')
# Change color of base inside
ax.patch.set_facecolor('#22312b')

#this is how we create the pitch
pitch = Pitch(pitch_type='statsbomb',
              pitch_color='#22312b', line_color='#c7d5cc')

# Set the axes to our Base
pitch.draw(ax=ax)
# X-Achsen => 0 to 120
# Y-Achsen => 80 to 0

# Lösung: Y-Achse invertieren:
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

#use a for loop to plot each pass
for x in range(len(df['x'])):
    if df['outcome'][x] == 'Successful':
        #plt.plot((df['x'][x],df['endX'][x]),(df['y'][x],df['endY'][x]),color='green')
        plt.scatter(df['x'][x],df['y'][x],color='green')
        **plt.arrow(df['x'][x],df['y'][x], df['endX'][x] - df['x'][x], df['endY'][x]-df['y'][x],
                  shape='full', color='green')** # Here is the problem!
        
    if df['outcome'][x] == 'Unsuccessful':
        plt.plot((df['x'][x],df['endX'][x]),(df['y'][x],df['endY'][x]),color='red')
        plt.scatter(df['x'][x],df['y'][x],color='red')

plt.title('Messi Pass Map vs Real Betis',color='white',size=20)
```

It always shows:

[image: Picture of output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that [`plt.arrow`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.arrow.html) has default values for `head_width` and `head_length`, which are too small for your figure. I.e. it *is* drawing arrows, the arrow heads are just way too tiny to see them (even if you zoom out). E.g. try something as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mplsoccer.pitch import Pitch

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mckayjohns/passmap/main/messibetis.csv')

...

# create a dict for the colors to avoid repetitive code
colors = {'Successful':'green', 'Unsuccessful':'red'}

for x in range(len(df['x'])):
    plt.scatter(df['x'][x],df['y'][x],color=colors[df.outcome[x]], marker=".")
    plt.arrow(df['x'][x],df['y'][x], df['endX'][x] - df['x'][x], 
              df['endY'][x]-df['y'][x], color=colors[df.outcome[x]],
              head_width=1, head_length=1, length_includes_head=True)

# setting `length_includes_head` to `True` ensures that the arrow head is
# *part* of the line, not added on top

plt.title('Messi Pass Map vs Real Betis',color='white',size=20)
```

Result:

[image: pitch with arrows]

Note that you can also use [`plt.annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html) for this, passing specific `props` to the parameter `arrowprops`. E.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mplsoccer.pitch import Pitch

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mckayjohns/passmap/main/messibetis.csv')

...

# create a dict for the colors to avoid repetitive code
colors = {'Successful':'green', 'Unsuccessful':'red'}

for x in range(len(df['x'])):
    plt.scatter(df['x'][x],df['y'][x],color=colors[df.outcome[x]], marker=".")
    
    props= {'arrowstyle': '-|>,head_width=0.25,head_length=0.5', 
            'color': colors[df.outcome[x]]}
    
    plt.annotate("", xy=(df['endX'][x],df['endY'][x]), 
                 xytext=(df['x'][x],df['y'][x]), arrowprops=props)

plt.title('Messi Pass Map vs Real Betis',color='white',size=20)
```

Result (a bit sharper, if you ask me, but maybe some tweaking with params in `plt.arrow` can also achieve that):

[image: Messi pitch]

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. But what was my actual problem? WOuld be cool to know the logical mistake I made.

Comment: Updated the answer. I would personally go for `plt.annotate`, because the result, at least for me here, looks sharper. But as mentioned, you might manage the same with `plt.arrow` when tweaking the params a bit. Not sure.

Comment: Ok, i got it. Thanks! Next time i'll check the values more. You're own solution is better!